# Rubymine - enable line numbers

Tags: ruby, rubymine

Does anybody know how I can enable line numbers for Ruby (and Ruby on Rails as well) projects?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This setting is located in `File` | `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `Appearance` | **Show line numbers**:

[image: show line numbers]

Comment: In Rubymine 4.5.4 its through View -> Acitve Editor -> View line numbers

Comment: @boddhisattva, no, the setting you mention works only for the active editor, while the setting from my answer is global and will affect all editor tabs permanently.

Comment: @CrazyCoder In that case, can you pls tell me where can I find the Editor option in the Rubymine IDE(I am new to Rubymine.. ).. ? I can see an 'Edit' option but no Editor option in the main tab options..

Comment: @boddhisattva, `File` | `Settings` | `Editor` | `Appearance`.

Comment: This may have been moved to `File` | `Settings` | `Editor` | `General` | `Appearance` in RubyMine 7 (Linux).

Answer (score 8):

On Rubymine 7.1, using a Mac, I found it under:

- Preferences --> Editor --> General --> Appearance

Near the top is a `Show line numbers` checkbox. See illustration.

[image: Illustration of the Preference in Mac OS X]

Answer (score 0):

On RubyMine 6.3 I used File->Settings...->Editor->Appearance and checked the box "Show line numbers" to enable them.